# Which OJDBC driver will go with oracle19.10.0.0?

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, oracle19c

We are using oracle version - 19.10.0.0
Java - 1.8

Which ojdbc driver version will be suitable for this combination?
I have found on the pages to use ojdbc8.jar for the above-mentioned specification. But which version of the jar should I use?

Comment: Refer to [Oracle JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 19.10 Oracle JDBC driver which is available either [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) or on Maven Central.